# Remote Profiling Jprofiler

Tags: jprofiler

Hi i am very new to Jprofiler & Linux.
I am trying to Monitor my Apache Tomcat server installed on a linux machine from Jprofiler remote profiling which is installed on windows machine. Kindly help me in the procedure in detail.
I tried all the Help i could get from google but still stuck..any help will is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7):

In any case, you should extract the JProfiler tar.gz file for Linux on the remote machine. No further configuration is required on the remote side. On the local side you need a full installation of JProfiler.

There are two ways to get remote profiling to work:

#### A. Attach to the running Tomcat process

Execute the command line utility `bin/jpenable` in the JProfiler distribution on the remote machine and select the Tomcat process. The JVM will then be ready for profiling. If the profiled JVM is not listed, execute jpenable as the same user that runs the Tomcat JVM. If that does help, use alternative B.

On the local machine, create a session of type "Attach to profiled JVM (local or remote)", specify the host name of the remote machine and the profiling port that was set with jpenable.

When you start session, the JProfiler GUI will connect to the remote machine and you will see profiling data.

#### B. Use the integration wizard

Execute the command line uutility `bin/jpintegrate` in the JProfiler distribution on the remote machine and select your application server and follow the subsequent steps.

Then, proceed as in alternative A. This option is actually preferable to alternative A and unless you have to profile an already running JVM, you should take this route.

Comment: I'm confused about this: I can neither find `jpenable` nor `jpintegrate` in the automatically created archive I extracted to the remote machine during installation...

Comment: For A, you have to extract the JProfiler archive from the download page on the remote machine which contains jpenable and jpintegrate. For B, you do not need jpenable or jpintegrate since the instructions on how to modify the start script are given by the integration wizard or have been performed by the integration wizard.

Comment: I got it to run. I think I used B, because I did not execute any of those files manually, just copied them... I wish this part would be a bit more verbosely explained in the new Session wizard.