# Profiling Mule Container and Application using JProfiler

Tags: profiling, mule, jprofiler

I am trying to profile Mule ESB apps deployed on a mule container(CE v3.4) using Jprofiler but have been unsuccessful this far.
My Mule server is running remotely on a linux 64 bit server and the jprofiler is running on my local windows machine. I am trying to remotely connect the jprofiler running on my local windows machine to the Mule server running remotely on a linux server, but till now I have failed to connect the local running jprofiler to the remotely running Mule server.

Has somebody done this before? What are the steps to be followed to connect my jprofiler running locally to Mule server running remotely on some different server?

Thanks and Regards
Jai

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/12265799/936832

Comment: Thanks Ingo for the comment. I am able to remotely connect to the Tomcat but not to Mule container. My job here is to connect to the Mule container and profile it remotely. In the integration wizard of jpintegrate of jprofiler I cannot see an an entry for Mule server listed. Which option among all server types available which are listed by jpintegrate should be selected for Mule server. The jpintegrate listed about 30+ server types with which you can integrate but I could not find an option for Mule server.

Comment: Just use the generic integration wizard, then you can manually add the VM parameter to the Java invocation of your server.

Comment: I tried with the generic integration wizard and added -agentpath:/TivoData/jprofiler/jprofiler8/bin/linux-x64/libjprofilerti.so=port=8849,nowait as the VM argument to the java invocation of the Mule Server but still I am not able to connect Jprofiler remotely to the Mule server. I believe the problem is with the Mule Server design and how it is built for remote profiling.

Comment: I need an example and steps if somebody has successfully profiled MuleServer remotely using the Jprofiler tool.

Answer (score 1):

Add these lines to conf/wrapper.conf:

```
wrapper.java.additional.4=-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=9999
wrapper.java.additional.5=-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false
wrapper.java.additional.6=-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false
```

and connect your profiler to port 9999