# Profiling Mule using Yourkit

Tags: profiling, mule, yourkit

Has somebody successfully profiled Mule standalone CE v3.4 using Yourkit?

The Mule documentation: http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/Profiling+Mule# has a download page link to download the Profiler Pack for Mule Community Edition but that link does not seem to work.

What are the exact steps to be followed for remotely profiling Mule standalone server CE using Yourkit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need the profiler pack anymore to profile Mule applications. Start Mule Standalone CE, then start YourKit and select MuleContainerBootstrap from the running JVMs list.

Comment: Thanks Ale for the input. Will this work in remote profiling also. I have Mule container installed on a remote linux server and Yourkit is running on my local Windows Machine. What are the additional steps required here to enable remote profiling using Yourkit.

Comment: Take a look at my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22957684/profiling-mule-container-and-application-using-jprofiler

Answer (score 0):

Please use "Remote Attach Wizard" [http://www.yourkit.com/docs/java/help/attach_wizard.jsp](http://www.yourkit.com/docs/java/help/attach%5fwizard.jsp)