# Is there anyway to trace a MuleMessage to know what flows were executed?

Tags: java, mule, message, trace

I'm curious if there is a way to know what Mule flows were executed by either looking at a MuleMessage or enabling some sort of tracing.  I'd like to find a quick and easy way to without resorting to inserting 'logger' entries in the mule-config.xml.  Mule Studio is not an option unfortunately.

Comment: Considering your question clearly says _ without resorting to inserting 'logger' entries in the mule-config.xml_... how come the logger solution is the accepted answer

Comment: There was no better alternative.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple Solution :- In each of the flow place a logger with a value #[flow.name] ... This will help to detect which flow has been executed ... for example :-  place a logger   `<logger message="Flow name:- #[flow.name]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>` will get the flow name in console .. you can use this logger in any flow to get the name ... you can use this Mule expression **#[flow.name]** to get the name of the flow

Answer (score 0):

Use a JMX console like VisualVM, JMC or JConsole. Start your Mule application and connect locally to org.mule.module.reboot.MuleContainerBootstrap with any of those tools. Then go to MBeans | Mule.appname | Flow | flowname and see the values in the attributes page.

If you need to do this remotely you can follow this guide: [Profiling Mule Container and Application using JProfiler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22957684/profiling-mule-container-and-application-using-jprofiler)

Answer (score 0):

With `Mule Management Console`, which is **only** `Enterprise Edition` feature, you could monitor mule applications, see which flows got triggered, inbound, outbound properties, flow variables at each stage. Monitor performance and all that stuff

https://www.mulesoft.com/platform/soa/management-console-mule-esb

http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/Mule+Management+Console